# Why am I entering a slo-mo when I'm trying to counter?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I've only been playing *Assassin's Creed 3* for a short while. In the beginning, playing as Haytham, you get into a fight on a ship, during which you learn fighting skills such as counter-kill. Animus says to first press "O" (playing on the PS3), then hit the Square button, but, it doesn't seem to work. After pressing "O" I seem to enter slo-mo. Afterwards, I've tried pressing every single button, but nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not played number three but I'm assuming the slo-mo is part of the counter?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the buttons *during* the slow motion?

Comment: You have to press the buttons during this slo-mo. It exists so you have some time to react

Comment: I experienced this when playing on the PC. You parry the attack but there is no option to counter, disarm or throw. It continued until I turned my back and ran and then re-engaged. Not sure how it was caused though. Very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The slowmotion during countering is part of the game mechanics. It gives you a moments time to think about which of the counter moves you wish to perform (counter-kill, disarm, throw or using the special item (Y for XBox, Triangle for PS).

Different enemies are immune to various moves after being countered. For example, various special enemies like the Jagers, Grenadiers or captains are immune to the counter-kill. They need to be knocked down or disarmed to then be finished of quickly as they are defenseless. Exceptions to this rule are the double kills, which occur automatically when two enemies attack Haytham / Connor and a counter move is performed.